# Getting contact relationship such as spouse from Google Contacts script interface

Tags: relationship, contacts, google-contacts-api

I am trying to access the "relationships" additional fields in google contacts via the apps script interface.  The docs show the "getCustomFields()" call, but it does not seem to contain any information from my contacts about spouse, child, or other relationships.

Anyone know, is there a separate call for accessing this data?  I don't see one in the docs:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/contact

Comment: Wtf, clickbait !

Comment: This is currently not supported by Contacts API. If you check the [guide](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/), there's no mention of such. Try to file a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new).